# Elementary property of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose we have integers satifying $a+b=c+d$ and $e+f=g+h$. Show that $ae+dh+bg+cf=cg+bf+de+ah.$

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: I've been playing around with it for about an hour but frustratingly still can't get it!

Comment: Supposed to just be an elementary check shouldn't use anything fancy

Comment: Note: Such a question can be solved *automatically* by treating the conditions as a system of linear equations, solving it by Gaussian elimination and rewriting both sides of the claimed equation in terms of the free variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when you get frustrated and don't see anything simple you can do explicit substitution.

If $a+b =c+d$ let $a = c+w$ (where $w = c-a$) and therefore $b= d-w$.

Replace $a$ with $c+w$ and $b$ with $d-w$ *everywhere*

$ae+dh+bg+cf = (c+w)e + dh + (d-w)g + cf= ce+we + dh + dg-wg + cf$ and $cg+bf+de+ah=cg + (d-w)f + ed + (c+w)h = cg + df -wf + ed +ch+wh$.

And if $e+f = g+h$ let $e=g+v$ and $f=h-v$

Replace $e$ with $g+v$ and $f$ with $h-v$ everywhere and we get

$ae+dh+bg+cf=c(g+v)+w(g+v) + dh + dg-wg + c(h-v)= cg+cv+wg+wv+dh+dg-wg+ch-cv=cg+wv+dh+dg+ch$ and $cg+bf+de+ah= cg + df -wf + ed +ch+wh= cg + d(h-v)-w(h-v) + (g+v)d + ch + wh = cg +dh-dv -wh+wv +gd+vd + ch + wh =cg +dh+wv +gd+ ch=cg+wv+dh+dg +ch$.

Those are both the same.

Now that's not a *good* way to do it but it a complete way to do it.

......

A better way would be to put like terms together and factor.

$ae+dh+bg+cf=cg+bf+de+ah \iff$

$ae-ah + dh-de = cg - bg + bf-cf \iff$

$a(e-h) -d(e-h)= g(c-b) -f(c-b) \iff$

$(a-d)(e-h) = (g-f)(b-c)$.

And we can probably get there by noticing that $a+b = c+d \implies (a-d)=(c-b)$  And $e+f = g+ h\implies e-h = g-f$

And we are done.  To put it in the right direction:

$a+b = c+d \implies (a-d)=(c-b)$

$e+f = g+ h\implies e-h = g-f$

So $(a-d)(e-h) = (c-b)(g-f)$

$ae -ah - de +dh = cg - cf -bg +bf$ so

$ae +dh + bg + sf = cg + bf + de + ah$

Comment: sf should be cf in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} a-d &\,=\, c-b\\
e-h &\,=\, g-f\\
\Rightarrow\ \ \ \ (a-d)\,(e-h) &\,=\, (c-b)\,(g-f)\\
\Rightarrow\ ae\!+\!dh \!-\!de \!-\! ah &\,=\, cg\!+\!bf\!-\!bg\!-\!cf
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: As an aside, the reason why this doesn't work for semirings (which is OP's other question - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3430463/property-of-semirings-rings-without-additive-inverses) is because of the usage of additive inverses.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a proof without using additive inverses? The original question is for a semiring with the additive cancellation property: $r+t_1=r+t_2$ implies $t_1=t_2$. I changed it to integers thinking I could modify the proof to a semiring but I realise now that that makes the problem trivial and I can't use that proof in the semiring case since it uses $-$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, WLOG, consider:
$$a\le c \Rightarrow \begin{cases}c=a+x\\ b=d+x\end{cases} \\
e\le g \Rightarrow \begin{cases}g=e+y\\ f=h+y\end{cases}$$
Hence:
$$ae+dh+\underbrace{(d+x)(e+y)}_{bg}+\underbrace{(a+x)(h+y)}_{cf}=\\
\underbrace{(a+x)(e+y)}_{cg}+\underbrace{(d+x)(h+y)}_{bf}+de+ah.$$